# What does DELIMITER // do in a Trigger?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, triggers, delimiter

```sql
DELIMITER //
```

What is the of use of it?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It changes the statement delimiter from `;` to `//`.  This is so you can write `;` in your trigger definition without the MySQL client misinterpreting that as meaning you're done with it.

Note that when changing back, it's `DELIMITER ;`, not `DELIMITER;` as I've seen people try to do.

Answer (score 35):

In SQL you close each statement with a delimiter, which is by default a semicolon (;). In a trigger you need to write multiple statements, each ending in a semicolon. To tell MySQL that those semicolons are not the end of your trigger statement, you temporarily change the delimiter from ; to //, so MySQL will know that the trigger statement only ends when it econunters a //.

Comment: I think you expressed it more clearly than the accepted answer!

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Add an example:
When working with mysql shell command, we used `;` delimiter to close each statement. However, in case, we want to build the store procedures and triggers, we need to add the semicolon `;` in these statements also.

```
delimiter //
create trigger log_students after insert on students
for each row
  begin
    insert into log_students(change_by, change_at) values(USER(), NOW());
  end//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple sets the end of statement delimiter (`;` semi-colon in standard, default SQL).
Changing the character could be useful if you want to use `;` in your SQL, or you are using embedded SQL (where it might lead to confusion). similarly the `//` in your example could lead to confusion in embedded SQL, or you might want to use it in your SQL. So imply use `DELIMITER` to set the delimiter that is appropriate for your application and needs.

Answer (score 0):

Read the (ummmm) [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

`delimiter` is the marker for the end of each command you send to the mysql command line client.

`delimiter` is not only related to triggers, but defining triggers and stored procedures is one strong use case as you wish them to contain semicolons (;) which are otherwise the default `delimiter`.

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter command below changes the default delimiter `;` to `//`. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql/77440483#77440483) explains delimiter in detail:

```sql
DELIMITER //
```

So, you can run the SQL statement below with `//` but not with `;`:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person//
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | David |
+----+-------+
```

Then, if you change the delimiter `//` back to `;`:

```sql
DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you can run the SQL statement below with `;` but not with `//`:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | David |
+----+-------+
```