# MySQL Trigger Update other Table

Tags: mysql

Please someone help me.

I`m trying to create a Trigger that when table1 is Updated table2 will also be updated.

Please Check.

```
CREATE TRIGGER up_trig
AFTER UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
begin
update table2
set name2 = name1
where name2 <> name1
and id2 = id1;

end
```

I really need this one please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the delimiter and the `;` after the end:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER up_trig
AFTER UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
begin
   update table2
   set name2 = NEW.name1
   where name2 <> NEW.name1
   and id2 = NEW.id1;
end;

|
```

Comment: and the answer to "why the delimiter?": http://stackoverflow.com/q/1346637/664479