# Setting up a trigger in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to comprehend triggers, and I think I fully understand them, but I haven't been able to implement any of them. I want this code to delete a user with the name "test". So if anyone updates their name to "test" the user should be deleted.

My example code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `my_trigger`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `my_db` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE `username` = 'test';
END
```

My error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

I can't figure out why the delete statement is giving me an error. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't do that (see answer bellow). But you can create a stored procedure, that updates the table, then deletes rows from this table (use transaction).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntaxically correct SQL:

```
DELIMITER ;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `my_trigger`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `my_trigger`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM my_table WHERE `username` = 'test';
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

But it won't work, because you can't delete from the table, you are updating:

> A trigger can access both old and new data in its own table. A trigger
>   can also affect other tables, but it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-9

If you want a simple example, try this:

```
DELIMITER ;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `my_trigger`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `my_trigger`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`username` = 'aaa';
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

This will always set 'aaa' as the user name when updating.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you have `DELIMITER` written up there. All of the examples/tutorials don't have that at all. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @EGHDK Changeing delimiter is necessary, because MySQL is seeing the first ";" as the end of the CREATE TRIGGER statement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346637/what-does-delimiter-do-in-a-trigger

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to associated trigger only with a table.

Also within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

[Restrictions on Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)