# Creating a trigger on insert on a table, that creates new rows on another table, according to amount of row on another (3rd) table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Assume the following structure:

Table1:

> ID | name

Table2:

> ID | name

Table3:

> ID | table1_id | table2_id | value

I want to build a trigger, after insert to Table1 if id not exist, to create new rows **for each row in Table2** inside Table3 with the corresponding IDs.

What I did so far is creating this logic in php, I have never created triggers this complex before so I don't really know how to approach this.

Example:

```
Customers Table after insert:
+----+------+
| ID | Name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Dan  |
+----+------+

Currency Table:
+----+------+
| ID | Name |
+----+------+
|  1 | USD  |
|  2 | EUR  |
+----+------+

Customers Currency Table after trigger
+----+---------------+-------------+-------+
| ID | customer_id   | currency_id | Value |
+----+---------------+-------------+-------+
|  1 |    1          |       1     | NULL  |
|  2 |    1          |       2     | NULL  |
+----+---------------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: give some data example how it will be inserted when you add something to table1.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Added example

Comment: Hmm so the currency table is predefined, nothing to insert there and when a new customer is added to customer table you want one row for that customer along with the currency id in 3rd table ? so if I add customer id 2 then 2 will be added 2 times in the 3rd table along with the currency ids 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Yes @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, is also important that it only adds it to the 3rd table if the ID on the 1st one doesnt exist. (I guess insert ignore and making it unique will do the trick)

Comment: well if your ID in the customer table is primary key auto incremented then duplicate situation will never arrive, each customer will have a unique id.

Comment: In which column the customerId may not be existed? in the ID column in 3th tbl or in the customer_id column in the 3th tbl?

Comment: @stmnmn it acctually can exist in Table1, in which case you shouldn't even trigger.

Comment: I didn't ask if it can exists in tbl1, I asked what do you meen "the id in the first table does not exist", not exists in which column in 3th table? (not in which table).

Comment: Yes, If the ID already exist in the 3rd table, I dont want it to reactivate the trigger again.

Perhaps the example below doesn't fit because the ID is unique, but in another scenario where I the column isn't unique I wanna know how to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with this you need to use cursor in trigger, here is a nice tutorial on this http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/

Now in your case I would suggest that the `customer` table id should be primary key auto incremented so that you always have unique value

So here how it should be

```
create table customer (id int primary key auto_increment , name varchar (100));

create table currency (id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(100));
insert into currency (name) values ('USD'),('EUR') ;

create table customer_currency (id int primary key auto_increment, customer_id int , currency_id int , val varchar(100));
```

The trigger will be something as

```
delimiter //
create trigger customer_add after insert on customer
for each row 
begin
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE currency_id int;
  DECLARE currency_val varchar(100);
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id,name FROM currency;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  OPEN cur;
        ins_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO currency_id,currency_val;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE ins_loop;
            END IF;
            INSERT INTO customer_currency (customer_id,currency_id,val) VALUES (NEW.id,currency_id,currency_val);
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
end ; //
delimiter ;
```

Now in mysql lets add a record on customer table

```
mysql> insert into customer (name) values ('Abhik') ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
```

Now lets see what is there in the customer_currency symbol

```
mysql> select * from customer_currency ;
+----+-------------+-------------+------+
| id | customer_id | currency_id | val  |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+
|  1 |           1 |           1 | USD  |
|  2 |           1 |           2 | EUR  |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+
```

In the trigger I am adding the currency value as well in the 3rd table if you do not want then can ignore that and it will become null.

You can write an after delete trigger on customer and delete the data from `customer_currency` where `customer_id` is the id of the deleted row in customer table.

Comment: Testing it, I'll let you know how it went in a minute.

Comment: Acctually the val should have been null on the insert, it's going to have a number there later on.
But I got the idea.

Comment: yes I mentioned that in the note if you do not want val then just change the insert query to `INSERT INTO customer_currency (customer_id,currency_id) VALUES (NEW.id,currency_id);`

Comment: What's the delimiter for btw?

Comment: check here it has some answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346637/what-does-delimiter-do-in-a-trigger

Comment: I know this doesn't fit this scenerio, but what if it was possible for the id from the customers table to be null or 0, in which case I don't want the trigger to activate, what must I change?

Comment: Ok After testing, it works.

Amazing help right there.

Answer (score 2):

Another option that you can use is:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `trg_bi`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_bi` BEFORE INSERT ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `table3` (`table1_id`, `table2_id`)
    SELECT NEW.`id`, `t2`.`id`
    FROM `table2` `t2`
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM `table1` `t1` WHERE `t1`.`id` = NEW.`id`);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is validated by the `id` column `table1`, but you can use the column you want to validate, however, depends as validate that there is no 'customer' in `table1`.

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b967e/1)</kbd>

Comment: This seems quite easier and more initiative, and doesn't use the cursors.

I'll give it a short.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind the: `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id = NEW.id);`

Comment: Nice usage without cursor +1

Comment: @DalaiLama: The logic behind the subquery is explained in [13.2.10.6 Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)