# Error creating a trigger to skip lines on insert in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, triggers

I am having an error and I can't make sense of it. Here is the code for my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_test
BEFORE INSERT ON player_totals FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Player = 'Player' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'basketball-reference duplicate header';
    END IF;
END;
```

I am getting red errors marks in MySQL workbench source code editor for 3 lines. For the line that begins `SIGNAL SQLSTATE ...`, It says:

> Syntax Error: missing 'semicolon'

For the line that reads `END IF;`, the error says:

> Syntax error: END (end) is not valid input as this position.

For the line that reads `END;`, the error says:

> Extraneous input found - expected end of statement

Just not sure how to fix these errors, from what I've seen this looks like the correct syntax...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this one, with `$$` after `END`

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_test
BEFORE INSERT ON player_totals 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Player = 'Player' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'basketball-reference duplicate header';
    END IF;
END; $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Now I am getting an error on the line: 'Delimiter;' that says: Syntax Error: 'Delimiter' (identifier) is not a valid input at this position.

Comment: If you put a space between Delimiter and the semicolon, then there are no more error marks for some reason.

Comment: This helped me too.  Thanks - and this post explains why DELIMITER is necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346637/what-does-delimiter-do-in-a-trigger