# Declaring variables inside Triggers

Tags: mysql, variables, triggers, mariadb

I'm getting an error on line 5(At the semi-colon at the first declaration), something isn't corresponding with MariaDB. Anyone had a similar problem, or know how to solve this kind of problem?

```
CREATE TRIGGER incative
BEFORE DELETE
ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE _user INT;
    DECLARE username  VARCHAR(150),_password  VARCHAR(150),
            email  VARCHAR(320),ip_address varchar(150),
            _data VARCHAR(120),_time VARCHAR(150);
    DECLARE _active int DEFAULT 1;

    SELECT * INTO _user, username, _password, email, ip_address,
                  _data, _time, _active
        FROM users WHERE ID_User = old.ID_User

    INSERT into users(_user, username, _password, email, ip_address,
                      _data, _time, _active)
END;
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why fetch the columns you already have in `old`?  Why reinsert the row you are deleting?  Wrong logic with `_active`?  Or with `into users`?

Comment: The update didn't worked so i had to try another solution. This solution looked better for me. If you know any better solution, this question is for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must add DELIMITER $$ before create...

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER incative
BEFORE DELETE .....
```

for more information you can check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1346645/1548932

I don't know the case for mariaDB but If you use Mysql you must change line 6 to :

```
DECLARE username,_password,email ,ip_address,_data,_time VARCHAR(150);
```

Or if the length are differents, you must declare one variable per line like :

```
DECLARE username  VARCHAR(150)
Declare email  VARCHAR(320)
```

And finaly don't forget ; at the end of line 8 and 10

Comment: The first line (DELIMITER $$) is showing me errors everytime i use semi-colon(;), i changed it to DELIMITER ; and i have made the changes you suggested and i still get the same error.
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4